# (Databricks SQL) Date stored as STRING (yyyyMMDD) cannot convert it into DATE (yyyy-MM-DD)

Tags: sql, date, databricks, azure-databricks, string-to-datetime

I've spent last 3 hours googling the issue but nothing seems to work in Databricks SQL version specifically. I have to use a database, where someone decided it's best to store date as a STRING, there's no way around it short-term.

Current date format (STRING) is following:
yyyyMMDD

What I want it to be is (DATE):
yyyy-MM-DD

I tried CAST, I tried CONVERT, I tried 5 different solutions from stack and other website but the code seems to be written for SQL Dev where there are more functions available and I am forced to work with Databricks. I'd be grateful for any help!

tx!

Comment: Can you show us your examples? And why are you using so many tags if the problem doesn't belong to that tags?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My apologies for the tags used - I'm new to the community.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Databricks, but after some googling, it looks like there is a [MAKE_DATE function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/make_date.html) that can help you. You can extract the year, month, and day values from your YYYYMMDD string. It might look something like this, if your date string is called ds:

```
MAKE_DATE(
  SUBSTRING(ds FROM 1 FOR 4),
  SUBSTRING(ds FROM 5 FOR 2),
  SUBSTRING(ds FROM 7 FOR 2)
)
```

If you want the code to be even more transparent, you can cast the substrings to integers yourself instead of relying on implicit conversion for the arguments to MAKE_DATE.